# Failed attempt to deploy web app for my UI: "Document undefined is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to deploy my script as a web app which I created within a spreadsheet. I have followed google's instructions and dealt with managing the version, but when I try to deploy the app I get the following message when I try to test the web app for my latest code: 
"Document undefined is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

I know the spreadsheet exists. I am deploying the app because I need the App URL as part of my code. I am trying to automate an approval process by email. When deploying the app I have selected the latest version, chosen to execute the app as "user accessing the web app" as I would like to share this app, and have set who has access to the app as "only myself". When I click the App URL that I send to my email I am also told that "the page (or document) you have requested does not exist."

I am very new to this. I followed this tutorial to get what I have: http://youtu.be/K2uLzJdEVCA

In the video however, it is not called deploying a web app, rather, it is called publishing the script. I suppose this is something new. In any case, I need the App URL.

Here is my code in case something within it is what is flawed.

```
function approve() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Editors');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var fName = row[1];
    var lName = row[2];
    var email = row[3];
    var approved = row[4];
    var notified = row[5];

    if(approved.toLowerCase() == 'yes' && notified.toLowerCase() != 'yes'){
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Request Approved: CI&W Community Edit Permission", "You may now make edits to the site!") ;
      data[i][5]= 'yes';
     }
  }
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(data);

}

function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Functions', [
    { name: 'Approve', functionName: 'approve' }
                     ]);

}

function onFormSub(event) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Editors');
  var fName = event.namedValues["First Name"];
  var lName = event.namedValues["Last Name"];
  var email = event.namedValues["Email"];
  var url = 'I paste in the app URL i am given here';
  url += '&spreadsheetId=' + spreadsheet.getId();
  url += '&row=' + sheet.getLastRow();
  Browser.msgBox(spreadsheet.getId())
  var message = 'Name: ' + fName + ' ' + lName + '\nEmail: ' + email + '\nApprove: ' + url;
  MailApp.sendEmail('fakeemail@gmail.com', 'New Edit Request: CI&W', message);


}

function doGet(event) {
  var spreadsheetId = event.parameter['spreadsheetId'];
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Editors');
  var row = event.parameter['row'];

  sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue('yes');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel();
  label.setText('The request was approved');
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webapp url needs to have 2 parameter : the spreadsheet Id and the row number. Did you test it with the parameters correctly added ?
This can be seen in the video as well (but hard to read because of violent video compression)
[image]

About the publish / deploy as webapp, you are right : the name of the process has changed but it is roughly the same... don't worry about that.

---

**EDIT :** after further examination, there was a '?' that was missing at the end of the url and before the parameters ! (this change is coming from the new way webapp urls are constructed)

code should be like this :

```
    function onFormSub(event) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Editors');
      var fName = event.namedValues["First Name"];
      var lName = event.namedValues["Last Name"];
      var email = event.namedValues["Email"];
      var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyIfU-Qxp7urPdsD1iuYY2arBIeHya2Z7UPgdvMib67kFHNUWbQ/exec?';
      url += '&spreadsheetId='+spreadsheet.getId()
      url += '&row=' + sheet.getLastRow();
      Browser.msgBox(spreadsheet.getId())
      var message = 'Name: ' + fName + ' ' + lName + '\nEmail: ' + email + '\nApprove: ' + url;
      MailApp.sendEmail('xxxx@gmail.com', 'New Edit Request: CI&W', message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Obviously I am very new, and didn't know you had to add a ?. What a silly simple thing for me to not know. The odd thing is that google still tells me that it can't find the document when I click the test link while deploying, but it works, so that doesn't matter. Thanks again!

Comment: This is normal since the test URL has no parameter and the parameter gives the spreadsheet ID. So the SS in indeed undefined.